# Appearing & Disappearing “Scroll to top” link with jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this [JQuery plugin](http://briancray.com/2009/10/06/scroll-to-top-link-jquery-css/) to show (Scroll to Top) button, but I want this link or button to be appeared after scrolling down of specific part of the page. For instance, inside the body tag I have many divs and many discription but I want the (scroll to Top) link to be appeared after scrolling down the third div inside the body.

What should I do to get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you just have to set the `top` to the position of your div:

try changing

```
var top = $(document.body).children(0).position().top;
```

to

```
var top = $('#your_div').offset().top;
```